# AR objects drift issue in Google TANGO

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I am trying to create a simple scene where a few objects are placed on the table. Object placement works perfect but when I move the device, the objects drift around a bit. Which at one point makes the objects placed at the corner feel like they are not on the table but floating in the air.

Even in the sun moon and earth example in Unity examples here: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity
The earth n moon drifts as you move the device

Is this a bug or is there any special setting which I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The objects drift because as the Tango device moves through space, it is only tracking its own position in 3D space. For objects to remain static in a dynamic environment, the device needs to understand the position of the placed objects in 3D space and their relation to the surroundings in order to anchor the objects and reduce drift.

Luckily, `TangoCore` has you covered here and the 3 Core technologies of **Motion Tracking**, **Depth Perception** and **Area Learning** all work together to help out.

If I'm not mistaken, the Sun and Moon example is the scene "SimpleAugmentedReality" under `tango-examples-unity / UnityExamples / Assets / TangoSDK / Examples / Scenes /`

However if you would like to anchor the objects in 3D space and reduce drift, you'll need to use Area Learning and Depth Perception as well. Area learning performs *Loop Closures* as the device realises it has "seen" an area before and adjusts the path and markers to provide a more accurate device and augmented content position.

So here is what you can do to learn what you need to. Save your current scene, go to open Scene and follow this path `tango-examples-unity / UnityExamples / Assets / TangoSDK / Examples / Scenes /` and load up some of the other scenes to get an understanding of how the technologies intertwine.

For example, you could load up the `ExperimentalMeshBuilderWithColour` scene, and learn how the Depth Processing works programmatically, and then load the `MotionTracking` scene and learn how to access and use Motion Tracking from the `TangoManager` Game Object. And finally (also probably most frustratingly difficult) learn how Area Learning is managed with the `AreaDescriptionManagement` and `AreaLearning` scenes.

This will not only solve your drift issues, but also give you a much fuller understanding of the capabilities of the Tango Technology and allow you to express your ideas much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. So in short it's not possible to remove drift, Right? 

And yep I have tried area learning but it still doesn't remove the drift issue.

Comment: It absolutely is possible to remove drift, it wouldn't be a very robust markerless AR technology if it couldn't. You could try using the Experimental Mesh Occlusion Example scene to see another . Scan an area description and at the same time generate a mesh. Then select the ADF you just created and start the game, once you have relocalizing, view the mesh to see it maintain in position thanks to the Area Learning APIs and then place an AR object, this should maintain its position in the real world.

Comment: Alright I'll dig deeper into Area Learning + mesh generation and see how it goes. Thanks.